# Transparent non-client area

Tags: winforms, winapi, nonclient

I am creating a TextBox control subclass using Windows Forms. I am using the WM_NCCALCSIZE to change the client area (to enlarge the non-client area) but I have not found any solution on how to make the non-client area transparent. 
Is there any simple way to paint to non-client area in WM_NCPAINT in transparent way to duplicate the underlying window's background in intersecting region of the child control?

Comment: I presume you are targeting C/C++ ??? Try this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/99623/how-to-draw-in-the-nonclient-area)

Answer (score 0):

UpdateLayeredWindow is what you need.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms997507.aspx